# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' error in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

The following code works just fine in python 2, but spits out the following error in python 3.6.1

```
model="XD4-170"
ssh.send("more off\n")
if ssh.recv_ready():
    output = ssh.recv(1000)
ssh.send("show system-info\n")
sleep(5)
output = ssh.recv(5000)
ll=output.split() # Python V3

for item in ll:
    if 'Model:' in item:
    mm=item.split()
    if mm[1]==model+',':
        print("Test Case 1.1 - PASS - Model is an " + model)
    else:
        print("Test Case 1.1 - FAIL - Model is not an " + model)
```

**Error Output:**

```
if "Model:" in item:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

A little guidance would be most appreciated.

Comment: try `if 'Model:' in item.decode():`

Comment: Actually I need the entire for loop converted to python 3 - Any help for this simple code snippet would be appreciated.  @RafaelCardoso, why are you adding a decode()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the major differences between Python 2.x and Python 3.x is that the latter makes a strict distinction between [strings and bytes](http://www.diveintopython3.net/strings.html).  The 
[`recv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) method on a socket (I'm *assuming* that's what `ssh` is, because your code doesn't show it being assigned) returns a `bytes` object, not a `str`.  And when you `split()` a `bytes` object, you get a `list` of `bytes`, so each `item` in your loop is also a `bytes` object.

So, when your code gets to the line `if 'Model:' in item:`, it's trying to find a `str` within a `bytes` object, which isn't valid.

There are two ways you can fix this:

- Change the substring to a `bytes` object: `if b'Model:' in item:`.
- Decode the `bytes` read from the socket to a string: `output = ssh.recv(5000).decode('UTF-8')`.